Is there a performance benefit to using c++'s std(::ranges)::uninitialized_... algorithms, and is it worth not having constexpr?
I'm implementing a container type that owns some memory which I am creating using std::make_unique_for_overwrite(). Given that this function is specifically returning a std::unique_ptr to uninitialized memory, I wanted to use the uninitialized memory algorithms provided by the standard. I only noticed that these functions weren't constexpr when trying to write tests using static_assert for my container, only to realize that my constexpr constructors weren't so constexpr after all due to my calls to std::ranges::uninitialized_copy().
My question is, what exactly is the difference between std::ranges::copy() and its uninitialized brother, std::ranges::uninitialized_copy(), and is there a significant enough perf difference to give up constexpr compatibility?

Possibly dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66030088/why-is-stduninitialized-copy-move-etc-not-constexpr

@康桓瑋 im not asking why it isn't constexpr, I'm asking if there is a significant enough difference between the two algorithms to prefer using one over the other

Probably no....

@SHIPWECK Then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67992613/why-are-there-c-algorithms-defined-specially-for-uninitialized-memory?

make_unique_for_overwrite and make_shared_for_overwrite are generally supposed to be used with trivial type. I don't get the logic behind not constraining them to those types. For other types, they just default construct the objects. For trivial types, assignment and copy constructor are functionally equivalent. uninitialized_copy is generally intended for C memory management, where the object allocation and construction are temporarily disjoint. I would rather define a costume allocator and create a vector instead.


Given that this function is specifically returning a std::unique_ptr to uninitialized memory

It isn't. It's a unique_ptr to a default-initialized object (or array or objects). This is not uninitialized: Using uninitialized_* algorithms will construct a new object over an existing object, possibly leaking memory if a destructor is missed.

The "performance benefits" of these algorithms is that the alternative is usually to default construct then use the assignment operator. This is really a "correctness" benefit, since you can't expect generic objects to be default constructible, but as a side effect you avoid a (possibly costly) default constructor.

And when you have two choices between a "constexpr-friendly" algorithm and a more performant algorithm, use if consteval and use both.

Oh, thank you! Then, what is the difference between std::make_unique and std::make_unique_for_overwrite? If I provide no arguments to std::make_unique, does it also default construct the object/array it's pointing to?

@SHIPWECK Basically, for classes it doesn't matter. The difference between make_unique<int[100]>() and make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(100) is that the first one will initialize with 100 zeroes and the second one will default-initialize (i.e., invalid to read, valid to write to)
